# How to add text at specific points at x-axis, at a cumulative histogram in plotly python

Tags: python, plotly

I produce the following cumulative histogram using plotly-express:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
px.histogram(pd.DataFrame({'N':[1,1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,7]}), x='N', 
             cumulative=True, nbins=7)
```

[image]

I would like to add as text, at points N=3*i (3,6,9,...etc) the value of `count`, above the bars

How could I do that ?

Comment: Try this: `px.histogram(pd.DataFrame({'N':[1,1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,7]}),x='N',     cumulative=True,text_auto=True,nbins=7)`

Comment: This adds to every bin though. I would like only to the bins 3,6,9,... etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this code

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# Create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'N': [1,1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,7]})

# Create a histogram
fig = px.histogram(df, x='N', cumulative=True, nbins=7)

# Add text above the bars at N=3*i (3,6,9,...)
for i in range(1, (max(df['N'])// 3) +1):
    pos_y = df[df['N']<=3*i].shape[0]
    pos_x = 3*i
    fig.add_annotation(x=pos_x, y=pos_y + 0.3,
            text=f'count = {pos_y}',
            showarrow=False)

# Show the plot
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my "hacky" solution, which adds also a line:

```
fig = px.histogram(pd.DataFrame({'N':[1,1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,7]}),x='N',     
             cumulative=True,nbins=7)
for x in [3, 6]:
    label = str((fig.data[0]['x'] <= x).sum())
    fig.add_vline(x=x, line_width=3, line_dash="dash", line_color="green", annotation_text=label)
fig.show()
```

[image]